# after refreshing page and adding new values old localstorage values get erased

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, event-handling, local-storage

My local storage works correctly but the only issue I've ran it to is when I try adding a new value after a page refresh the previously stored values get erased. I think it may be because I'm using the same key.

```
I tried this localStorage.setItem("name_"+new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(favs))
```

but it didn't help.

This is my function to add a value and store it in to localstorage

**value is a string from an array**

```
const favs [];
 
   function addValue(e) {
        if (e.target.value !== "") {
          if (!favs.includes(e.target.value)) {
            favs.push(e.target.value);
            localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
            console.log(favs);
            document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML =  favs
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You keep reinitializing `favs` to an empty array. Instead of `const favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name') || "[]");`

Comment: Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it please

Comment: No, this is definitely a duplicate. I'm not here for rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you reload the page you're re-initializing favs instead of loading it from the localStorage so it's overwriting it when you save the first value. What you need to do is get the value from the localStorage first and then push the new value. You can do this on page load or when you first try to push the value to localStorage, like so:

```
let favs = [];
 
   function addValue(e) {
        if (e.target.value !== "") {
          if (favs === []) {
            favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
          }

          if (!favs.includes(e.target.value)) {
            favs.push(e.target.value);
            localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
            console.log(favs);
            document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML =  favs
          }
        }
      }
```